# How to use apt get update without such errors?

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

I need to use sudo apt-get update, but it gives me tons of errors. i tried to use sudo apt-get update --fix-missing, but also it gives me errors. 
here is the output:

```
**

Err:1 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial InRelease         Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds
Err:2    http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/ InRelease               Could not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection    timed out
Err:3    http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial    InRelease                                                           Could not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection    timed out 
Err:4 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease     Could not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection    timed out
Err:5 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates    InRelease                                                                Unable to connect to 10.149.10.11:8080:
Err:6    http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           Unable to connect to 10.149.10.11:8080:
Err:7    http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              Could not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection    timed out
Err:8 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease     Could not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection    timed out 
Err:9 http://archive.canonical.com (lsb_release InRelease      Could not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection    timed out   
Err:10 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease           Unable to connect to 10.149.10.11:8080: 
Err:11    http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   Could not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection    timed out 
Err:12 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty    InRelease                                                                Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds Reading package    lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch    http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not    connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection timed out 
W:    Failed to fetch    http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease     Unable to connect to 10.149.10.11:8080: 
W: Failed to fetch    http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease     Unable to connect to 10.149.10.11:8080:  
W: Failed to fetch    http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease     Could not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection    timed out 
W: Failed to fetch    http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Could not    connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection timed out 
W:    Failed to fetch    https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-xenial/InRelease     Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds 
W: Failed to fetch    http://archive.canonical.com/dists/(lsb_release/InRelease  Could not    connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection timed out 
W:    Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/xenial/InRelease     Unable to connect to 10.149.10.11:8080: 
W: Failed to fetch    http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/InRelease  Could not    connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection timed out 
W: Failed to fetch    https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-trusty/InRelease     Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds 
W: Failed to fetch    http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could    not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection timed out    
W: Failed to fetch    http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease    Could not connect to 10.149.10.11:8080 (10.149.10.11), connection    timed out 
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been    ignored, or old ones used instead.

**
```

Comment: Check your internet connection with `ping  askubuntu.com`

Comment: @George i tested it and it receives and respond successfully, but the problem still exist.

Comment: @Zanna no, it's a proxy issue.

Comment: @Hathout do you have a proxy that you have to use going outbound to the Internet on your environment?  If so, go check the proxy because it's failing to connect to the upstream proxy at `10.149.10.11` on port `8080`, and that's why you're getting those errors.

Answer (score -1):

This is either your Internet connection issue, if not, make sure if any proxy is being set for the connection and is authenticated.

Comment: There is no proxies and the problem still exist